# Git did not clean properly (exit code 57)

Tags: git, github

When I am pulling changes in git, git don't ask my ssh password and throws an error:

> Git did not clean properly (exit code 57)

I haven't found any solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your ssh key.

Create and add a new key to your account and it will fix the problem.

---

If you are using GitHub login to your account and the key will be grayed out.

---

#### How to generate ssh keys:

Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"
```

Once you have your key set in home/.ssh directory (or Users/.ssh under windows), open it (**copy the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**) to your clipboard.

#### Add keys to Stash

- Login to your stash account
- Under your user name (right corner) click on manage account
- find the ssh section and add your key from the previous step.

Comment: I am using Git Stash.Plz elaborate how to create new ssh key.

Comment: Updating the answer.

Comment: I am able to clone push or fetch.Each time git asks for password but during pull.It throws an error: git.exe pull -v --no-rebase --progess "origin"